# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus help

Tags: calculus

I am working on a problem set assigned to us by my professor. One item is to find the derivative of g

$g(x)=\int_a^b \dfrac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}~du$ where a=2x and b=3x.

A hint was given and it confuses me:

$g(x)=\int_a^b f(u)~du= \int_a^0 f(u)~du + \int_0^b f(u)~du$ where a=2x and b=3x

Why is this so?

Comment: What part of the hint is confusing? An integral can be broken into two parts as has been done. Use the FTC to find the derivative of g by evaluating each part.

Comment: Correct.  The equality $\int_a^b f(u)du = \int_a^0 f(u)du + \int_0^b f(u)du$ has nothing whatsoever to do with $g(x)$ or with $a=2x$ and $b=3x$.  It's an independent fact.  Also helpful is the fact that $\int_a^0 f(u)du = -\int_0^a f(u)du$.

Comment: @Vladhagen I thought you can only break an integral in two parts if in [a,b] there is a c where a<=c<=b. What I can understand is how a<=0<=b

Comment: Notice that if a<0, then 0 lies in between a and b (Assuming that b is positive). If a>0, then the integral from a to 0 will actually be negative from the integral from 0 to a. Doc's comment is useful in this regard. You can always split the integral at 0. Then, regardless of whether a and b are negative or positive, the integrals will give you the correct answer. One way to see this is to try it with several values of a and b on the function $x^2$ or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really do not even need the hint. Just use chain rule on both parts.

$g'(x) = f(b)\frac{db}{dx} - f(a)\frac{da}{dx}= 3\frac{9x^2-1}{9x^2 +1}-2\frac{4x^2-1}{4x^2 +1}$

This is also what the hint would give you, except that you would have two parts where you evaluate f(u) at 0 and multiply by the derivative of 0 (which is zero)

In general, if $g(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(u) du$ then $g'(x) = f(b)\cdot b'(x) - f(a)\cdot a'(x)$.